# Horizontal Listview Loading same images from URL (Using Picasso)

Tags: android, picasso, horizontallist

I've this code snipped. Its a horizontal list view. Problem is that same images are being loaded instead of different ones. What can be the issue? I don't think picasso is the issue over here. I guess its something else.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
//      View timeLineRow = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dashboardtimelinerow, null);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.toprecommendationsitem, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.recommimage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.recommimage);
            holder.userImage = (CircularImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userImage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        int i=0;
        for(i=0; i<mArrayListData.size(); i++) {
            if (!mArrayListData.get(i).getDishimageurl().isEmpty()) {
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(mArrayListData.get(i).getDishimageurl())
                        .resize(172, 172)

                        .into(holder.recommimage);
                break;

            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the value of `position` anywhere inside your `getView` function. `getView` is supposed to return the view for whichever piece of data lies at index `position` in the array or list you passed in. You'll want to replace your code with something like

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.toprecommendationsitem, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.recommimage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.recommimage);
        holder.userImage = (CircularImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userImage);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (!mArrayListData.get(position).getDishimageurl().isEmpty()) {
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                 .load(mArrayListData.get(position).getDishimageurl())
                 .resize(172, 172)
                 .into(holder.recommimage);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```